# Google Caliper: can't complete benchmark (The worker exited without producing data)

Tags: java, caliper

When I try to run a benchmark method with [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/), it exits before completing any measurements.  I confirmed in debugger that Caliper is executing the benchmark method twice, when it is going through its *dry run* phase.  But when it tries to run the experiments it exits before completing anything.

The benchmark method is very simple (although it calls a lot of other application code):

```
@Benchmark
public int testNewOrder(int reps) {
    OrderRequest newOrder = this.newOrder;
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
        router.getWorker().processOrderRequest(USER_CONN_ID, newOrder, System.currentTimeMillis());
        mockFixEngineManager.clear();           
    }
    return 10;
}
```

Running with `--verbose` doesn't yield any different output that I can see.  The entire output is:

```
Experiment selection: 
  Instruments:   [allocation, runtime]
  User parameters:   {}
  Virtual machines:  [default]
  Selection type:    Full cartesian product

This selection yields 2 experiments.
Starting experiment 1 of 2: {instrument=allocation, benchmarkMethod=testNewOrder, vm=default, parameters={}}… The worker exited without producing data. It has likely crashed. Run with --verbose to see any worker output.
```

I am running on Windows 7, using JDK 1.7.0_40 (in case that makes a difference).  I ran the Caliper code through the debugger, and I see it is exiting here:

```
// ExperimentingCaliperRun.java, line 384

     processFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
          if (!pipeReaderFuture.isDone()) {
            // the process completed without the pipe ever being written to.  it crashed.
            // TODO(gak): get the output from the worker so we can know why it crashed
            stdout.print("The worker exited without producing data. "
                + "It has likely crashed. Run with --verbose to see any worker output.\n");
            stdout.flush();
            System.exit(1);
          }
        }
      }, MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor());
```

`pipeReaderFuture.isDone()` returns false.  I'm not sure why.  There are no errors written to stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [Caliper Issue #230](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/issues/detail?can=2&q=230&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=230).  After I posted the failure detail, the developers were able to post a fix. To get the fix, you'll need to pull the latest from the [Git repositor](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/source/checkout)y to get the fix.